# Webpage logo appears different in Firefox

Tags: wordpress, firefox

My website appears different in firefox compared to chrome or safari, the logo image at the top of the page is placed higher towards the top of the page.

I have tried using vertical-align but had no luck. Any suggestions? (page is institute101.com)

```
header .logo img.standard {
display: none;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The page is even more messed up in IE, is there a general rule I should keep in mind when making a page compatible for all browsers?

Comment: Could be `line-height` or something. Best thing to do is include a CSS normalizer before your own custom rules, that will ensure that most things are consistent among browsers. Google for options

Comment: Ok I will check that out in google now. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in layout is because Firefox is not honouring the 30px padding on your `body` element. Firefox seems to be ignoring that.

The problem is highly likely to be the dreaded Quirks Mode.

Many browsers will put the page into quirks mode if the site does not begin with a valid Doctype. The problem with quirks mode is that it works differently in different browsers.

Your page does have a doctype, but importantly, it is not the first thing in the page, and that is why it is going into quirks mode -- you have some rogue CSS and javascript tags before it; these need to be moved into the `<head>` section of your page.

Fixing this will **definitely** solve the problem as far as IE is concerned. It will *probably* solve the problem for Firefox.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Very well laid out answer! That fixed it straight away, looks fine in IE now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from [this css file](http://institute101.com/wp-content/themes/moustachey/framework/meanthemes-options.php?ver=20121030):

Last row of this file is:

```
body { margin:0; padding:30px 0 0; }
```

if you delete the padding you'll have the same appearance with Firefox.

Comment: I wanted to make firefox look like the way it did in chrome with the padding on top, so instead of deleting that line I added it to the themes main style.css aswell, rather than just having it in the themes control panel customer css block. I guess firefox did not recognize the themes custom css block. Thanks for your help